# Download Blob From Blob Storage Using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download an excel file on a blob. However, it keeps generating the error "The specified blob does not exist". This error happens at blob_client.download_blob() although I can get the blob_client. Any idea why or other ways I can connect using managed identity?

```
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
 
blob_url = BlobServiceClient('url', credential = default_credential)
   
container_client = blob_url.get_container_client('xx-xx-data')

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client('TEST.xlsx')

downloaded_blob = blob_client.download_blob()

df=pd.read_excel(downloaded_blob.content_as_bytes(), sheet_name='Test',skiprows=2)
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if `TEST.xlsx` blob exists in `it-dashboards-data` blob container?

Comment: Yes it does. Checked it multiple times...

Comment: Please note that blob names are case sensitive. Blob should be exactly named `TEST.xlsx`.

Comment: Yes..I copied and pasted the name in from the blob URL

Comment: Is the `url` simple blob URL like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob` or is it a SAS URL?

Comment: It’s a simple blob URL

Comment: Aah...I see. Let me provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I have to also provide 'Reader' access on top of 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' to be able to identify the blob. There was no need for SAS URL.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because each request to Azure Blob Storage must be an authenticated request. Only exception to this is when you're reading (downloading) a blob from a public blob container. In all likelihood, the blob container holding this blob is having a `Private` ACL and since you're sending an unauthenticated request, you're getting this error.

I would recommend using a `Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL` for the blob with `Read` permission instead of simple blob URL. Since a SAS URL has authorization information embedded in the URL itself (`sig` portion), you should be able to download the blob provided SAS is valid and has not expired.

Please see this for more information on Shared Access Signature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature.

Comment: Is there a way to create SAS URL using DefaultAzureCredential()? I have to just download a blob using managed identity. I'd read through the link and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Can you confirm if managed identity is working for you? Are you running the code in Azure or locally?

Comment: Yes it’s working correctly. I’m already using managed identity for authenticating with SQL. Just that I’m having issues with storage blob. I’m testing locally and in Azure, both seems to have issues